# Replace a textNode with mixed-content HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

#### For this HTML node:

```
<div><i>foo</i> and <i>bar</i> go ### with <b>baz</b></div>
```

I would like to replace the string `###` with another node (`<u>well</u>`), without replacing the entire `innerHTML` of the wrapper `div`.

#### Expected result:

```
<div><i>foo</i> and <i>bar</i> go <u>well</u> with <b>baz</b></div>
```

My approach was to iterate the *childNodes*, filter only the `TEXT_NODE` elements with the string i would like to replace and replace those textNodes with `replaceChild` using a DOM Fragment to hold the replaced content:

```js
var root = document.querySelector('div'),
    tag = "<u>well</u>",
    tempFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    children = root.childNodes,
    replacedString;

 for( var i = children.length; i--; ){
      if( children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && 
          children[i].nodeValue.length > 1        && 
          children[i].nodeValue.indexOf('###') != -1 ){
       
            replacedString = children[i].nodeValue.replace('###', tag);

            console.log( replacedString );
            tempFrag.innerHTML = replacedString;
            children[i].parentNode.replaceChild(tempFrag, children[i])
      }    
}
```

```html
<div><i>foo</i> and <i>bar</i> go ### with <b>baz</b></div>
```

---

As you can see, replacing a `textNode` in this manner doesn't work as expected.

While I can manually extract each part of the *replacedString* and break it into:

```
`before textNode` / New element / `after textNode`
```

and piece them all in, that would create a lot of code (this is actually the way i'm currently doing it, and am trying to think of a smarter way, but the fragment didn't help with the parsing & insertion as you can see)

Comment: For anyone wondering, it's for my script [Tagify](http://localhost/tagify/#section-mix)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
replacedString = inputChildren[i].nodeValue.replace('###', tag);
```

You can use

```
var offset = ...indexOf('###');
replacementNode = textnode.splitText(offset);
```

And then by adding

```
textnode.parent.insertBefore(wrapper, replacementNode);
```

you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Split helped, I've managed to piece a working example (posted as an answer) but I still had to replace the `###` string in `replacementNode` since it was still present

Answer (score 0):

```js
var root = document.querySelector('div'),
    tag = document.createElement('u'),
    children = root.childNodes,
    replacedNode,
    idx;

 tag.innerHTML = "well";
 
 for( var i = children.length; i--; ){
      if( children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && 
          children[i].nodeValue.length > 1 ){
            idx = children[i].nodeValue.indexOf('###');
            if( idx == -1 ) continue;
            
            replacedNode = children[i].splitText(idx);
            // remove '###' from the second split textNode ('### with')
            replacedNode.nodeValue = replacedNode.nodeValue.replace('###', '');
            // put the tag element before the second split textNode
            children[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tag, replacedNode);
      }    
}
```

```html
<div><i>foo</i> and <i>bar</i> go ### with <b>baz</b></div>
```